# Unable to save a React´s state hook into the database, even with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I need to get a React´s state hook into the database, whenever it gets its value changed... I tried even useEffect() hook, but either way, I still can't save it in the database. Actually it is being saved in a lazy behaviour, i.e I input one value nothing happens, than I do it again and then I get the data saved

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { addDays, format, parse } from 'date-fns';
import { reverseFormatNumber } from '../../helpers/functions';
import { ptBR } from 'date-fns/locale';
const handdleAddIncome =() =>{

const incomes = (incomesToBeUpdated) =>{

 const [dateEl, setDateEl] = useState(format(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM'));
 const [valueEl, setValueEl] = useState('0');
 const [updatedIncome, setUpdatedIncome] = useState(incomesToBeUpdated);
 useEffect(()=>{
   let incomeObject = {};
    incomeObject[format(parse(dateEl, 'yyyy-MM', new Date()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')] = reverseFormatNumber(valueEl);

    var index = updatedIncome.map((key) => Object.keys(key)[0]).indexOf(Object.keys(incomeObject)[0]);
    handleAddIncome({ incomes: updatedIncome }, dateEl, valueEl, index);
        
  },[updatedIncome])
return(<button onClick={()=>handdleIncome()}>Save</button>)
}
```

I have two functions in my logic: `handleIncome`, this one is to handle the data to be saved in the database, and `handleAddIncome`, which is related to get things in the database saved...

```
 const handleIncome = () => {
    setDateEl(document.querySelector('#IncomeDate').value);
    setValueEl(document.querySelector('#IncomeValue').value);

    let incomeObject = {};
    incomeObject[
      format(parse(dateEl, 'yyyy-MM', new Date()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    ] = reverseFormatNumber(valueEl);

    const index = updatedIncome
      .map((key) => Object.keys(key)[0])
      .indexOf(Object.keys(incomeObject)[0]);

    if (index !== -1) {
      updatedIncome[index] = incomeObject;
      setUpdatedIncome(updatedIncome);
    } else {
      setUpdatedIncome(
        [...updatedIncome, incomeObject].sort(
          (a, b) => new Date(Object.keys(a)[0]) - new Date(Object.keys(b)[0])
        )
      );
    }      
    toggleAddIncome(null, true);
    
  };

const handleAddIncome = async (incomesObj, index) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
    await axios
      .post(`/api/investments/${id}/incomes`, incomesObj, config)
      .then((response) => {
        const dates = updatedIncome
          .filter((invest) => Object.values(invest)[0] !== null)
          .map((key) => Object.keys(key).map((date) => date))
          .flat()
          .map((data) => {
            let datePartes = data.split('-');
            return `${datePartes[2]}/${datePartes[1]}/${datePartes[0]}`;
          });

        const IncomesTemp = updatedIncome
          .filter((invest) => Object.values(invest)[0] !== null)
          .map((key) => Object.values(key)[0]);

        let temparray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < IncomesTemp.length; i++) {
          temparray.push([dates[i], IncomesTemp[i]]);
        }

        setNewIncomes(temparray);

        setAccruedIncome(
          Number(
            updatedIncome
             .map((key) => Object.values(key)[0])
             .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0)
             .toFixed(2)
           )
          );
      })
     .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data);
      });
```

For those iof you who want to take a look on my code I actually have a codesandbox link here  https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-frog-d0zrq?file=/src/components/Incomes/Incomes.js In this link you will find a working example of what I meant

And in this other link you will find the route for the investment https://d0zrq.csb.app/admin/investment/60b2696de8be014bac79a2a1 where you can check out the behaviour about I have written above... Whenever you click in the plus sign

[image]

You can also test the other method routes such as edit and remove

Comment: It looks like you're doing this outside of a valid React component. You shouldn't be defining useState within the function... that should be on the component itself.

Comment: Also setting state is asynchronous. I think you are trying to use it before it is set but not exactly sure where

Comment: Is `handdleAddIncome` different than `handleAddIncome`? `handleAddIncome` and `handdleIncome` both seem undefined in the first snippet, and overall the first snippet looks like an invalid React component. How and where does the second snippet relate to the first?

Comment: @yoursweater... The component's name is income

Comment: @DrewReese, yes they are different... They are in the second just to get things organized

Comment: Yes, @charlietfl... That's exactly what I'm struggling with the fact that setting state is asynchronous...
Do you know how can I handle this situation?

Comment: Best thing I can suggest is scale this down to a really simple case that you can send to a test endpoint then build it back up. Hard to help without being able to run this

Comment: "Do you know how can I handle this situation?" Yes, enqueue the state update and use an `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency to issue side-effect. This or just keep using the value you are updating state with in the callback.

Comment: How come? Enqueue state update?
Could you please refer me a tutorial for that? @DrewReese

Comment: Ok... I am trying to find some sort of explanation on how to perform that, @DrewReese

Comment: You can leverage the [React component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to enqueue a state update and "react" to it updating to issue further side-effects via a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.

Comment: Well, this article is not using hooks, but I am using hooks... There isn't any approach available when dealing with hooks?
Thanks anyway, @DrewReese

Comment: What article are you working from? The React component lifecycle functions *outside* class-based and functional components, it's the same for either. It's a fairly trivial matter to convert from one to the other.

Comment: Hey, @charlietfl.. I've managed toi put my project on the web...
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-frog-d0zrq?file=/src/components/Incomes/Incomes.js

In this link you will find a working example of what I meant

And in this other link you will find the route for the investment https://d0zrq.csb.app/admin/investment/60b2696de8be014bac79a2a1